# How to summarize the data generated in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a Crystal report whose sample output is below:

```
C_name P_name   Code         P. Rev F. rev  C.rev  
ABC    AAA      ABC-1-1      100    1100    1100  
ABC    AAA      ABC-1-2      200    1200    1200  
ABC    AAA      ABC-1-3      300    1300    2300  
XYZ    BBB      XYZ-1-1      200    1200    2200  
XYZ    BBB      XYZ-1-2      150    1150    3150  
DEF    CCC      DEF-5-1      400    1400    1400  
DEF    CCC      DEF-5-6      100    1100    2100  
DEF    CCC      DEF-5-9      200    1200    4200  
DEF    DDD      DEF-8-11     300    1300    2300  
DEF    DDD      DEF-8-12     400    1400     400
```

Now, I want to add up the values for max value of Code. For example, ABC have 3 codes out of which ABC-1-3 is the latest code. So I want to dsiplay one record for these 3 records and add up the revenue values for 3 records and display it in one row only. The final output should look like below:

```
ABC  AAA    ABC-1-3     600 3600    4600  
XYZ  BBB    XYZ-1-2     350 2350    5350  
DEF  CCC    DEF-5-9     700 3700    7700  
DEF  DDD    DEF-8-12    700 2700    2700
```

Please help..
Thanks

Comment: I think the best would be group these records from code itself and then showing the same.As within a group you want to get the latest record and then also sum of the group.

Comment: Please format the code as it is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert Group and `P_name` is the Group field which you select to create your group then in `Running Total Fields` and create new field for each of `P.Rev`  `F.rev`  `C.rev` in Evaluate and Reset part click `on change of group` and chose Type of summary `Sum` and for the `Code` field do the same,just chose Type of summary `maximum`. now you can add new fields to your Group and see the result.